# javascript - convert font element to span element using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, dom

I want to convert `<font>` element to `<span>` element like this using regex:

#### Input:

```
[some strings...]<span [something]></span><font ...>[sometext]</font>[some strings...]
```

#### Output:

```
[some strings...]<span [something]>[sometext]</span>[some strings...]
```

> Note: The input/output is a string.

In shortly, I want to remove the `<font>` element and move the contents of that into `<span>` element keeping the attributes of the `<span>` element.

I've tried this:

```
const rx = /<span(.*?)><\/span>([^<\\s]+?|\\s*)<font(?:\\s+[^>]*)?>(.*?)<\/font>/gi;

inputStr.replace(rx, function(match, p1, p2, p3) { return `${p2}<span${p1}>${p3}</span>`; });
```

However it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: just in case. it would be much more readable, flexible and maintainable if you use DOM traversing instead of text-level substitution. Do you have to use RegExp only?

Comment: I completely agree with @skyboyer [I think a link to this answer in needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @skyboyer Unfortunately, I have to use only regex. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also agree with @skyboyer, this is not the best way, but if you can use regexp only or if this is a one-time task, you can use a class group specifing to take all chars that are not ">", in this way you can take all the params of the tag span and use it in the font:

```
var text = 'Some text... <span style="color:red"></span><font style="margin:10px">Hi there!</font> other text <span style="color:blu"></span><font style="margin:10px">doh!</font> final text';
console.log(text.replace(/<span([^>]*)><\/span><font[^>]*>(.+?)<\/font>/gi,'<span$1>$2</span>'));
```

edited in order to match other tags inside  (except other s, obviously)

Comment: What if there are `<br>` or other tags in `[sometext]`?

Comment: ah! you're right, I've not thinked about that case... you just need to change the group inside <font> with one with a lazy operator (.+?), so js will grabs as little as possible before matching the </font>

Answer (score 0):

Use any ID or class selector if possible, I have used here tag name just for example, if you have a Id selector then remove [0] from code.
This or with some modification should work for you

```
document.getElementsByTagName("font")[0].replaceWith('<span>' + document.getElementsByTagName("font")[0].innerHTML +'</span>')
```

Using Jquery,

```
$("YOUR_DOM_SELECTOR").replaceWith('<span>' + $("YOUR_DOM_SELECTOR").html() +'</span>')
```

Comment: I have to use only Regex. ;( Thank you for your answer.